# Unit test - Link in React using Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I have Link inside component. I have specified the route path in app.js.

When I tried to find **Link** control inside the component using Swallow and Mount it throws error.

Can anyone share the example to find link button inside component 
    **code**

```
 it('includes link to Next Exam', () => {
        const home = shallow(
          <StaticRouter>
            <ComponentForm/>
          </StaticRouter>,
        );
        expect(home.find(Link)).toHaveLength(1);
      });
```

Comment: Please share the code you are trying to use and we can help you see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Updated the code

Comment: Is `Link` in the `ComponentForm` or in the `StaticRouter`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst It is in ComponentForm. StaticRouter I placed as I was getting some error at the time of running test.

Answer (score 3):

[Enzyme `shallow`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) specifically is meant to NOT be able to test children of the component being passed. Because `StaticRouter` is the parent component, `ComponentForm` is never getting properly rendered, and so `Link` will never be in the view. So, using `shallow` you can test that `StaticRouter` properly renders a `ComponentForm`, but you cannot look inside `ComponentForm`.

You have two options:

First, you could just pass `ComponentForm` to the `shallow` method. You mentioned in comments that this caused things to break. That's likely because `ComponentForm` expects props from `StaticRouter`. You can pass these manually:

```
shallow(<ComponentForm routerProp1={'foo'} routerProp2={'bar'} />);
```

Your other option is to to a deep render using [Enzyme `render`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/render.md). Simply replace `shallow` with `render` and that should work. Do note that this is discouraged for several reasons. First, as noted with `shallow`, by not doing a `shallow` render, you possibly allow yourself to test things which the component you are passing in has no knowledge of. For example, `StaticRouter` has no knowledge about `ComponentForm`'s `Link`, and so the test for `ComponentForm`'s `Link` should be independent of `StaticRouter`. Second, `render` is much slower than `shallow`, so if you have lots of tests and lots of components, you will notice a considerable slowdown.